Pricing the payoff $V_T = S_T(S_T - K)^{+}$ - Change of numeraire and Girsanov
When we switch numeraires from $M$ to $S$, we change the measure from $\mathbb{Q}^M$ to $\mathbb{Q}^S$.
I derived a closed-form formula for the payoff $S_T(S_T - K)\mathbf{1}_{\{S_T > K\}}$ here.
Questions:

Is my math on-point?
How do I know the drift term $\theta$ when I applicate Girsanov change-of-measure?


Pricing the payoff $V_T = S_T(S_T - K)^{+}.$
Solution.
Under the risk-neutral measure $\mathbb{Q}^M$ associated with the money-market account numeraire $M(t)$, the stock price $S(t)$ evolves according to:
$$
\begin{align*}
dS_t = r S_t dt + \sigma S_t dW^{\mathbb{Q}^M}
\end{align*}
$$ {#eq-diffusion}
which has the solution:
$$
\begin{align*}
S_t = S_0\exp\left[\left(r - \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)t + \sigma W^{\mathbb{Q}^M}(t)\right]
\end{align*}
$$ {#eq-solution-of-gbm}
By the risk-neutral pricing formula, we have:
$$
\begin{align*}
V(0) &= \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}^M}\left[\frac{V(T)}{M(T)}\right] \\
&= \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}^M}\left[\frac{S_T}{M_T}(S_T - K)^{+}\right]
\end{align*}
$$ {#eq-risk-neutral}
By the change-of-measure formula, if $S(T)$ is any other numeraire with associated probability measure $\mathbb{Q}^S$, we know that:
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}^S}[V(T)]=\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}^M}\left[\frac{d\mathbb{Q}^S}{d\mathbb{Q}^M}V(T)\right]
\end{align*}
$$ {#eq-change-of-measure}
The Radon-Nikodym derivative $d\mathbb{Q}^S/d\mathbb{Q}^M$ is simply:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{d\mathbb{Q}^S}{d\mathbb{Q}^M} = \frac{S(T)/S(0)}{M(T)/M(0)}  = \frac{1}{S(0)}\cdot \frac{S(T)}{M(T)} = \exp\left[-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}T + \sigma W^{\mathbb{Q}^M_T}]\right]
\end{align*}
$$ {#eq-radon-nikodym}
Comparing this with the expression $\exp[-\theta W^{\mathbb{Q}^M}_T-\frac{1}{2}\theta^2 T]$, we get that $\theta = -\sigma$. So:
$$
W^{\mathbb{Q}^S}_T = W^{\mathbb{Q}^M}_T - \sigma T
$$ {#eq-girsanov-drift}
So, the $\mathbb{Q}^S$ dynamics of the stock price is:
$$
\begin{align*}
S_T &= S_0 \exp\left[\left(r - \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)T + \sigma (W^{\mathbb{Q}^S}_T + \sigma T)\right]\\
&=  S_0 \exp\left[\left(r + \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)T + \sigma (W^{\mathbb{Q}^S}_T)\right]
\end{align*}
$$ {#eq-Qs-dynamics}
We can develop the expression in @eq-risk-neutral to be:
$$
\begin{align*}
V(0) &= S_0\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}^M}\left[\frac{1}{S_0}\frac{S_T}{M_T}(S_T - K)^{+}\right]
\end{align*}
$$ {#eq-develop-the-expression}
Applying the change-of-measure (abstract Baye's formula),we have:
$$
\begin{align*}
V(0) &= S_0\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}^S}\left[(S_T - K)^{+}\right]
\end{align*}
$$ {#eq-applying-change-of-measure-formula}
Now, we have:
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{Q}^S(S_T > K) &= \mathbb{Q}^S\left(S_0 \exp\left[\left(r + \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)T + \sigma (W^{\mathbb{Q}^S}_T)\right] > K\right)\\
&= \mathbb{Q}^S\left(S_0 \exp\left[\left(r + \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)T + \sigma (-\sqrt{T}Z)\right] > K\right)\\
&= \mathbb{Q}^S\left(\log \frac{S_0}{K}  + \left(r + \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)T   > \sigma\sqrt{T}Z\right)\\
\end{align*}
$$ {#eq-probability-under-stock-measure}
where we subbed $-\sqrt{T}Z=W^{\mathbb{Q}^S}_T$. Recall, the standard normals $Z$ and $-Z$ have the same distribution by symmetry.
Define
$$
d_{-} = \frac{\log \frac{S_0}{K}  + \left(r + \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)T}{\sigma\sqrt{T}}
$$ {#eq-expression-for-d2}
Then, since $Z \sim \mathcal{N}^{\mathbb{Q}^S}(0,1)$:
$$
\mathbb{Q}^S(S_T > K) = \mathbb{Q}^S(Z < d_{-}) = \Phi(d_{-})
$$ {#eq-STgtKprobability}
So, we can expand the expectation in @eq-applying-change-of-measure-formula. The indicator random variable $1_{\{S_T > K\}}$ is $1$ for all points $Z < d_{-}$. So, the limits of integration will be $-\infty$ to $d_{-}$.
$$
\begin{align*}
V(0) &= S_0\left[\int_{-\infty}^{d_{-}} S_T  d\mathbb{Q}^S - K\int_{-\infty}^{d_{-}} dQ^S\right]\\
&= S_0\left[\int_{-\infty}^{d_{-}} S_T f_Z^{\mathbb{Q}^S}(z)dz - K\int_{-\infty}^{d_{-}} f_Z^{\mathbb{Q}^S}(z)dz\right]\\
&= S_0\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{d_{-}} S_0 \exp\left[\left(r + \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)T - \sigma \sqrt{T}z\right] \exp(-\frac{z^2}{2})dz - K\Phi(d_{-})\right]
\end{align*}
$$
Completing the square, we have:
$$
\begin{align*}
V(0) &= S_0\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{d_{-}} S_0 \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}(z^2 + 2\sigma\sqrt{T}z + (\sigma \sqrt{T})^2)\right] \exp\left[\left(r + \sigma^2\right)T\right]dz - K\Phi(d_{-})\right]\\
&=S_0 \left[S_0\frac{e^{(r + \sigma^2) T}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{d_{-}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(z + \sigma\sqrt{T})^2\right) dz - K\Phi(d_{-})\right]\\
\end{align*}
$$
Let $u = z + \sigma\sqrt{T}$. And define:
$$
d_{+} = d_{-} + \sigma \sqrt{T} = \frac{\log \frac{S_0}{K} + \left(r + \frac{3}{2}\sigma^2\right)}{\sigma \sqrt{T}}
$$
We have the closed-form formula:
$$
V(0) = S_0^2 e^{(r+\sigma^2)T} \Phi(d_{+}) - KS_0 \Phi(d_{-})
$$

I’ve lost you here: “By the change-of-measure formula”. In what follows should this be true for any numeraire or exactly for the S? Coz the latter is all but any

Here is an integral-free, measure-change free approach to computing the risk-neutral price using only Black-Scholes formulas. Consider $dS_t/S_t=\xi dt +\sigma dW_t^\xi,\xi \in \mathbb{R}$. Note that, since $S_T,K\geq 0$,
$$\begin{aligned}E^\xi[S_T(S_T-K)^+]&=E^\xi[S_T^2\mathbf{1}_{\{S_T\geq K\}}]-KE^\xi[S_T\mathbf{1}_{\{S_T\geq K\}}]
\end{aligned}$$
So we have, from the standard Black-Scholes formula
$$\begin{aligned}E^\xi[S_T\mathbf{1}_{\{S_T\geq K\}}]&=S_0e^{\xi T}\Phi(d^\xi_1)\\
d^\xi_1&:=\frac{\ln(S_0/K)+(\xi+\sigma^2/2)T}{\sigma\sqrt{T}}
\end{aligned}$$
and by noting that $E^\xi[S_T^2\mathbf{1}_{\{S_T\geq K\}}]=E^\xi[S_T^2\mathbf{1}_{\{S_T^2\geq K^2\}}]$ and that
$$d(S_t^2)=(2\xi+\sigma^2)(S_t^2)dt+2\sigma (S_t^2)dW_t^\xi$$
we use again Black-Scholes to compute
$\begin{aligned}E^\xi[S_T^2\mathbf{1}_{\{S_T\geq K\}}]&=S_0^2e^{(2\xi+\sigma^2) T}\Phi(d^\xi_2)\\
d^\xi_2&:=\frac{\ln(S_0^2/K^2)+(2\xi+3\sigma^2)T}{2\sigma\sqrt{T}}=\frac{\ln(S_0/K)+(\xi+3\sigma^2/2)T}{\sigma\sqrt{T}}
\end{aligned}$
so
$$E^\xi[S_T(S_T-K)^+]=S_0^2e^{(2\xi+\sigma^2) T}\Phi(d^\xi_2)-e^{\xi T}KS_0\Phi(d^\xi_1)$$
Under the risk-neutral measure, $\xi=r$. So the risk-neutral price is
$$e^{-rT}E^Q[S_T(S_T-K)^+]=S_0^2e^{(r+\sigma^2) T}\Phi(d^r_2)-KS_0\Phi(d^r_1)$$
